# I want to add a top and bottom scrollbar to a gridview in yii2

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2

I have a gridview in Yii2 and I want to add a scroll bar to the top and bottom. I downloaded jquery.doubleScroll and if I have a table on the page in a div with the class "double-scroll" I see a scroll bar at the top and the bottom. However, when I added the gridview, also in a div with the class "double-scroll" I am only seeing the scroll bar that appears by default with the gridview. I've also tried adding the class "grid-view" to the script to no avail

my javascript and style

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.double-scroll').doubleScroll();
                $('.grid-view').doubleScroll();
                $('#sample2').doubleScroll({resetOnWindowResize: true});
            });
        </script>
```

```
       <style>
           .double-scroll {
               width: 400px;
           }

       </style>
```

my table which produces a scroll bar top and bottom

```
<div class="double-scroll">
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
            <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
            <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
            <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
            <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
            <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
            <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
            <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
            <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
            <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
            <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
            <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
            <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
            <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
            <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AAAAAAAAA</td>
            <td>BBBBBBBBB</td>
            <td>CCCCCCCCC</td>
            <td>DDDDDDDDD</td>
            <td>EEEEEEEEE</td>
            <td>FFFFFFFFF</td>
            <td>GGGGGGGGG</td>
            <td>HHHHHHHHH</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

my gridview that has only the default gridview one

```
<div class="double-scroll">
<?php
    $gridColumns = '';

    echo DGridView::widget([

        'id' => 'task-template-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'class' => 'double-scroll',
        'pager' => [
            'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
            'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
            'maxButtonCount' => 20,
        ],
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
    ]);
?>
</div>
```

is it possible to do?

Comment: its pretty straight forward, but you need to explain what output is produced by the gridview, also you are using `DGridView` which isnt the default one, are you using a custom `Gridview` by extending the default? or some other plugin please mention

Comment: also if you can provide the output source for the gridview it would be helpful to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work, I used this as an example http://jsfiddle.net/simo/67xSL/
this works perfectly

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('.wrapper1').on('scroll', function (e) {
            $('.wrapper2').scrollLeft($('.wrapper1').scrollLeft());
        }); 
        $('.wrapper2').on('scroll', function (e) {
            $('.wrapper1').scrollLeft($('.wrapper2').scrollLeft());
        });
    });
    $(window).on('load', function (e) {

        $('.div1').width($('table').width());
        $('.div2').width($('table').width());
    });
    </script>

    <style>
    .wrapper1, .wrapper2 { width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; }
    .wrapper1 { height: 20px; }
    .wrapper2 {}
    .div1 { height: 20px; }
    .div2 { overflow: none; }
    </style>

~~

page
```

```
 <div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="div2">

    <?php
    $export_str = '';
    $panel_legend = '';
    $gridColumns = '';

    echo DGridView::widget([

        'id' => 'task-template-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'class' => 'double-scroll',
        'pager' => [
            'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
            'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
            'maxButtonCount' => 20,
        ],
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
    ]);
    ?>

    </div>
    </div>
```

```
I've lost the page with the name of the person who posted this, so sorry not to mention you by name, but thanks for your help
```

Comment: this answer doesnt address the original question or the plugin used.